# get file name and file type using split function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this filename

> test.123.5.jpg

```
var filename=file[0].name.split('.')[0];
var filetype=file[0].name.split('.')[1];
```

If there is only single dots then it is working but when multiple dots cannot retrieve file name and size individually.

Comment: The title asks for name and type, the body name and size. What parts do you need? And what's an example for _"but when multiple dots..."_?

Comment: Don't split the same thing multiple times with the same separator. Do it once, and store the result in a variable.

Comment: If you have access to the file itself, you can check its MIME type instead of trying to decipher the file type manually (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type).

Answer (score 2):

A very straightforward, easy to read solution:

```js
const testString = 'test.123.5.jpg';

const lastDot = testString.lastIndexOf('.'); // exactly what it says on the tin
const name = testString.slice(0, lastDot); // characters from the start to the last dot
const extension = testString.slice(lastDot + 1); // characters after the last dot

console.log(name);
console.log(extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this;

```js
const testString = 'test.123.5.jpg';
const fileData = testString.split('.');
    
const filename=fileData.shift();
 
const  filetype=fileData.pop();
    
const fileSize=fileData.join('.');
    
console.log("filename",filename);
console.log("filetype",filetype);
console.log("fileSize",fileSize);
```